# How to convert a list of ndarray arrays into list in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of ten 1-dimension-ndarrays, where each on hold a string, and I would like to one long list where every item will be a string (without using ndarrays anymore). How should I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need convert to array first, then flatten by [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and last convert to `list`:

```
a = [np.array([x]) for x in list('abcdefghij')]
print (a)
[array(['a'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['b'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['c'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['d'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['e'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['f'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['g'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['h'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['i'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['j'],
      dtype='<U1')]

b = np.array(a).ravel().tolist()
print (b)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Another solution with flattenting by [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from  itertools import chain

b = list(chain.from_iterable(a))
print (b)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that accomplishes my request:
    x = [str(i[0]) for i in the_list]

Comment: Is necessary convert to `str`?

Answer (score 0):

A good general purpose way of 'flattening' out the inner arrays of a list (or object dtype array of arrays) is to use one of the `concatenate` functions.

For example with a list that contains arrays of different lengths, including a 0d one):

```
In [600]: ll = [np.array('one'), np.array(['two','three']),np.array(['four'])]
In [601]: ll
Out[601]: 
[array('one',
       dtype='<U3'), array(['two', 'three'],
       dtype='<U5'), array(['four'],
       dtype='<U4')]
In [602]: np.hstack(ll).tolist()
Out[602]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
In [603]: np.hstack(ll).tolist()
Out[603]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

I had to use `hstack` because I included a 0d array; if they'd all been 1d `concatenate` would be enough.

---

If the arrays all contain one string, then the other solutions work fine

```
In [608]: ll = [np.array(['one']), np.array(['two']),np.array(['three']),np.array(['four'])]
In [609]: ll
Out[609]: 
[array(['one'],
       dtype='<U3'), array(['two'],
       dtype='<U3'), array(['three'],
       dtype='<U5'), array(['four'],
       dtype='<U4')]

In [610]: np.hstack(ll).tolist()
Out[610]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

In [611]: np.array(ll)
Out[611]: 
array([['one'],
       ['two'],
       ['three'],
       ['four']],
      dtype='<U5')  # a 2d array which can be raveled to 1d

In [612]: [i[0] for i in ll]         # extracting the one element from each array
Out[612]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```